# Bind a single RIA Entity in View

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, ria, prism-4

I can't get why this works (binds a single Car to RadDataForm):

xaml:

```
<tk:RadDataForm ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}"
    AutoGenerateFields="True" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

viewmodel:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    carId = int.Parse(navigationContext.Parameters["IdRecord"]);
    Cars= _carContext.GetCarById(carId);
}

private IEnumerable<Car> cars;
public IEnumerable<Car> Cars
{
    get { return this.cars; }
    set
    {
        if (this.cars!= value)
        {
            this.cars= value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Cars);
        }
    }
}
```

and this **not**:

xaml:

```
<tk:RadDataForm CurrentItem="{Binding Path=CurrentCar}"
    AutoGenerateFields="True" DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

viewmodel:

```
public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
{
    carId = int.Parse(navigationContext.Parameters["IdRecord"]);
    CurrentCar= _carContext.GetCarById(carId).FirstOrDefault();
}

private Car currentCar;
public Car CurrentCar
{
    get { return this.currentCar; }
    set
    {
        if (this.currentCar!= value)
        {
            this.currentCar= value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.CurrentCar);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't want a IEnumerable<> because I want to get a single Entity.
And, by the way, I want to understand what is going wrong...

Answer (score 0):

When binding to a single entity you should use `CurrentItem` instead of `ItemsSource`.

Comment: Thank you but it not works too. I edit the code with your suggestion.

Comment: I found that for retrieve a single entity I have to define a service that return a single TEntity and not a IEnumerable<TEntity> or IQueryable<TEntity>. This way works, thank you.